# Возможно ли каждую страницу обрабатывать одним и тем-же контроллером? laravel

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть страницы и hedaer, footer, и в hedaer, есть отдел категорий. Есть ли какие то приспособления что бы каждый раз не создавать новый контроллер, а каждую страницу обрабатывать одним и тем-же добиваясь с базы данных список категорий? Наверное это можно сделать с помощи ajax. Или есть какие то альтернативные варианты? Если так визуально представить то есть много страниц, каждая страница подключает header, footer, и надо что-бы hedaer имел постоянный доступ без создание многочисленных контроллеров для страниц к доступе категорий только один `контроллер`.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Причём тут header и причём тут контроллеры

Comment: А ответ на "Возможно ли каждую страницу обрабатывать одним и тем-же контроллером?"  --- да. Хоть 100500 страниц обрабатывайте. Только это бессмысленно. Всё равно что заставлять микроволновку ещё и печь блины, замораживать продукты, возить по городу пассажиров и тереть спинку в ванне

Comment: У вас категории это одна сущность, вы же не будете под каждую из 100500 категорий делать отдельные контроллеры?

Comment: скорее всего Вы используете Blade, поэтому для таких целей используйте View Composers: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/views#view-composers